# Monitoring queue depth of resque/resque-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm looking for a way to monitor the "queue depth" of my resque and resque-scheduler redis instances. Currently I am using god to ensure the resque and resque-scheduler tasks are running, and I use Scout to monitor my Rails application in general. What I am looking for is a way to monitor the number and rate of jobs being scheduled and executed. (Basically, I feel pretty confident that I will know of a problem with resque where it is just plainly not running, but I am more concerned about a scenario where the job queue is getting backed up or some other event has caused a large number of jobs to be scheduled, possibly due to some other error.)

I'm using redistogo in this application, though that may not be significant to how I approach the problem. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Scout provides a resque monitor plugin but it didn't support resque-scheduler and seemed to default the namespace in a different way than the resque gem. I forked the [source for the Scout plugin from jnewland](https://github.com/jnewland/scout-plugins/blob/master/resque_stats/resque_stats.rb) and made some enhancements that added resque-scheduler support as well as matching the default namespace in the resque gem and some other configuration options. If this is helpful to anyone else, I've [made it available on github](https://github.com/hartct/scout-plugins/blob/master/resque_stats/resque_stats.rb) and issued a pull request.